# is there any pkexec equivalent for windows cmd/powershell?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, unix, cmd

I have an GUI program and I want to run a command as ***administrator*** sometimes.
Is there any thing like `pkexec` for windows?

I tried `runas` command but its ask a password in cmd, which i dont want it...

```
runas /user:administrator "command"
```

I want something Like `pkexec` which ask password in GUI

or just that popup when we right click on a program and click Run as administrator come up.

Comment: In Windows you use impersonation. You should use a function like [`LogonUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera) or [`LogonUserEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserexa) to authenticate. If successful you get a token back. Then, you use the token in subsequent calls to other API functions.

Answer (score 0):

Launching a process with `Start-Process`, using the `-Credential` parameter will prompt the user for the password - in `powershell.exe` this will result in a windows credential ui dialog popping up:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -Credential $ENV:ComputerName\AdminUser
```